# What's wrong with this MovingMap structure?

Tags: time-series

This page from Mathematica 10 example:
https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/expanded-time-series-processes/model-the-conditional-value-at-risk-with-an-archpr.html

Has a problem with this command:

```
VaR = MovingMap[Sqrt[κ + {a, b}.(#^2)] quantile &, applLast, 2]
```

Returns the error message:

> "Tensors {0.165773,0.0892862} and
>   {0.000236628,0.0000288969,0.000123249} have incompatible shapes"

Any ideas what's wrong? Your help is much, much appreciated.

Comment: kglr's solution works. Infinite thanks. You just gotta change the DateListPlot to ListLinePlot to see the results. Here's the code: ListLinePlot[{applLast["Values"], VaR}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"returns", "value at risk"}]

Answer (score 2):

```
vaR = MovingMap[Sqrt[κ + {a, b}.(#^2)] quantile &, applLast["States"][[1]], 1]
```

works without error (version 11.3 - Wolfram Cloud).

The problem with the original code: `{a,b}` is a two-vector, while `MovingMap` with window argument 2 produces 3-vectors, hence the error message:

```
 MovingMap[Mean, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3],
  Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5]}, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: That `MovingMap` expression returns a different expression when run in version 10.0 vs 10.3.